# Strange beaver when use order_by with conditions Cannot resolve keyword '-pub_date into field

Tags: python, django

This code work fine, except it's not the result that i want.  For each Case it's order goes by to old one to new one

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), status="published").order_by(
                Case(When(status_ranking='1', then='pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='2', then='pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='3', then='pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='4', then='pub_date')).asc()
                )
```

Whenever i use this method, i got the error; **Cannot resolve keyword '-pub_date into field**

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), status="published").order_by(
                Case(When(status_ranking='1', then='-pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='2', then='-pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='3', then='-pub_date')).asc(),
                Case(When(status_ranking='4', then='-pub_date')).asc()
                )
```

Comment: You should use `.desc()` instead of `.asc()`. But I honestly don't see what all this `Case(..)`s are about. Why not just `.order_by('pub_date')`?

Comment: Beaver or behaviour ?

Comment: consider to use `.order_by("pub_date")` or `.order_by("-pub_date")`

Comment: What if you try to use value like this? - `then=Value('-pub_date'))`

Comment: @Charnel: these are not values I think, but the name of the column (so `F('pub_date')` so to speak.

Comment: If you first want to sort on `status_ranking` (ascending), and then on `pub_date` (descending), you can use `.order_by('status_ranking', '-pub_date')`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem value here will only wrap field with "minus" prefix in expression. idk so far if this will work but worth trying. At the same time `F` object may work or may not.

Comment: @Charnel: because to order in *descending* order, one prefixes the field name with a hypthen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.desc()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc) instead of [**`.asc()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.asc) to order in *desc*ending order.

That being said, it is quite *unreadable* what you aim to do. If you first want to sort on the `status_ranking` (in ascending order), and then on `pub_date` (in descending order), you can use:

```
return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), status='published'
).order_by('status_ranking', '-pub_date')
```

or if you only want to order in the status rankings for one to four:

```
return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), status='published'
).order_by('status_ranking', Case(When(status_ranking__in=[1,2,3,4], then='pub_date')).desc())
```

Comment: Maybe this worth asking OP - do he needs same ordering for status ranking or he need only this ordering for first four ranks. In second case your answer will not work.

Comment: @Charnel: then it would be better to use a `status_ranking__in=[1,2,3,4]`. But definitely not with multiple lines :)